# Image clone to usb stick for Mac Book Pro

Tags: software-installation, macbook-pro

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my MacBook Pro OS X Yosemite 10.10.2. I'm following a guide that states I need to clone an image to my usb stick using the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/image.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2
```

It's taking forever. I'm up to 45 mins. Have any of you tried this or know how long it should take or have any better recommendations on how to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs171/materials/pdfs/How_to_Dual-Boot_OSX_and_Ubuntu.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There's two things you can do:

- Use the `bs` parameter to tell `dd` how much to copy at a time, e.g. the following will copy the data in 4MB chunks instead of the relatively small default, which *may* speed it up:

  ```
  sudo dd if=/path/to/image.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=4M
  ```
- Since you're on Mac OSX, you can also press Ctrl + Tab, and `dd` [will give you a progress report](https://superuser.com/questions/794751/is-there-a-way-to-output-the-status-of-dd-on-os-x-during-the-copy-process), which you can use to see how much data it's already copied, and how much time is remaining.